# Thread culture not being honored in Embedded Code Blocks

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET Webforms website which has a base page class which changes the Thread culture based on the user configuration. We're basically doing this:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
   Culture = UICulture = Customer.Culture;
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(Customer.Culture);

   base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

Customer.Culture is just some data I get from the DB, so I can get an `en-us`or `fr-CA` and it's working... almost.

I found out that the CurrentCulture is not being honored in Embedded Code Blocks like

```
<%= MyPrice %>
```

Whereas it's working perfect if I do

```
<%# MyPrice %>
```

And then I call the DataBind method.

So, besides the expected answer "You should switch to DataBinding expressions" Is there any reason why the Culture is not being Honored?

Answer (score 2):

After digging into the .NET Framework source code I found why this is working in this way.

I (and many .NET developers?) thought that `<%= %>` was the equivalent to `Response.Write` but, in fact, it could be considered as the equivalent of `HtmlTextWriter.Writer` inside the Page.Render method.

If take a look at the TextWriter class, the Write method looks like this (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,275)

```
public virtual void Write(double value) {
     Write(value.ToString(FormatProvider));
}
```

So the key here is, what is `FormatProvider`?. I would expect this to be equals to `CurrentThread.Culture` but if we check the `HtmlTextWriter`, this is the constructor being used:(https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/HTMLTextWriter.cs,653):

```
public HtmlTextWriter(TextWriter writer, string tabString) : base(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) {
```

All in all, `<%=%>` will be processed not using the `CurrentThread.Culture` but `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.